# How to update a text box in an HTML form when another text box is filled in?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a form that has several fields. Among those fields are several weight fields. I have a `ScaleInWeight`, `ScaleOutWeight`, `BOLWeight`, `ScaleWeight`, and `ScaleDiff`. The first three are weights that are either entered or captured from the scale. The `ScaleWeight` is the difference between the `ScaleInWeight` and `ScaleOutWeight`, and the `ScaleDiff` is the difference between the `BOLWeight` and `ScaleWeight`. There are several other fields as well, but they don't matter for this, here is my form:

```
    <form action="ScaleTimes.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table id="getApt" class="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton"  name="findApt" value="Find"></td>
                <td>Appointment Number<br><input type="text" name="AptNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptNo'])){ echo $_POST['AptNo'];} ?>" required autofocus="true"></td>
                <td>Appointment Date<br><input type="date" name="AptDate" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptDate'])){ echo $_POST['AptDate'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Appointment Period<br>
                    <select name="AptPeriod">
                        <option value="">Select. . .</option>
                        <option value="3">6-8</option>
                        <option value="4">8-10</option>
                        <option value="5">10-12</option>
                        <option value="6">12-14</option>
                        <option value="7">14-16</option>
                        <option value="9">Open</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" name="ScaleInWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInWeight'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale In Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleInDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" name="ScaleOutWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutWeight'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale Out Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleOutDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer<br><input type="text" name="Customer" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Customer'])){ echo $_POST['Customer'];} ?>" autocomplete="on"></td>
                <td>Carrier<br><input type="text" name="Carrier" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Carrier'])){ echo $_POST['Carrier'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Driver<br><input type="text" name="Driver" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Driver'])){ echo $_POST['Driver'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Weighed By<br>
                    <select name="WeighedBy">
                        <option value="">Select Name...</option>
                        <option value="Tia Rian">Tia Rian</option>
                        <option value="Bruce Tippy">Bruce Tippy</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BOL Weight<br><input type="text" name="BOLWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLWeight'])){ echo $_POST['BOLWeight'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale Weight<br><input type="text" name="ScaleWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleWeight'];} ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Scale Difference<br><input type="text" name="ScaleWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleDiff'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleDiff'];} ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Truck Number<br><input type="text" name="TruckNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TruckNo'])){ echo $_POST['TruckNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Trailer Number<br><input type="text" name="TrailerNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TrailerNo'])){ echo $_POST['TrailerNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>BOL Number<br><input type="text" name="BOLNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLNo'])){ echo $_POST['BOLNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>AX Purchase Order<br><input type="text" name="AxPurchaseOrder" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'])){ echo $_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                <td><a href="http://LaFargaWebSRV:8080/ScaleTimeDashboard.php" class="OrderButton">Dashboard</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to update the `ScaleWeight` and `ScaleDiff` as the other weights are entered.

For example, when the `ScaleInWeight` is captured nothing happens.

When the `ScaleOutWeight` is then also captured then there should be a calculation that will give me the `ScaleWeight` (*absolute value only*)

Then when the `BOLWeight` is added to the form the `ScaleDeff` should also be calculated (*absolute value only*).

So if the `ScaleInWeight` is captured as 31920 and the `ScaleOutWeight` is captured as 74660 then the `ScaleWeight` should calculate to 42740.

When the `BOLWeight` is entered as 42731, then the `ScaleDeff` should calculate to 9.

**EDIT**

I have made a change to the form to add a function called `UpdateInfo` like so:

```
    <form action="ScaleTimes.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ScaleTime">
        <table id="getApt" class="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton"  name="findApt" value="Find"></td>
                <td>Appointment Number<br><input type="text" name="AptNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptNo'])){ echo $_POST['AptNo'];} ?>" required autofocus="true"></td>
                <td>Appointment Date<br><input type="date" name="AptDate" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptDate'])){ echo $_POST['AptDate'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Appointment Period<br>
                    <select name="AptPeriod">
                        <option value="">Select. . .</option>
                        <option value="3">6-8</option>
                        <option value="4">8-10</option>
                        <option value="5">10-12</option>
                        <option value="6">12-14</option>
                        <option value="7">14-16</option>
                        <option value="9">Open</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" name="ScaleInWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale In Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleInDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" name="ScaleOutWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Out Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleOutDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer<br><input type="text" name="Customer" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Customer'])){ echo $_POST['Customer'];} ?>" autocomplete="on"></td>
                <td>Carrier<br><input type="text" name="Carrier" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Carrier'])){ echo $_POST['Carrier'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Driver<br><input type="text" name="Driver" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Driver'])){ echo $_POST['Driver'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Weighed By<br>
                    <select name="WeighedBy">
                        <option value="">Select Name...</option>
                        <option value="Tia Rian">Tia Rian</option>
                        <option value="Bruce Tippy">Bruce Tippy</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BOL Weight<br><input type="text" name="BOLWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLWeight'])){ echo $_POST['BOLWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Weight<br><input type="text" name="ScaleWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleWeight'];} ?>" disabled onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Difference<br><input type="text" name="ScaleWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleDiff'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleDiff'];} ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Truck Number<br><input type="text" name="TruckNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TruckNo'])){ echo $_POST['TruckNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Trailer Number<br><input type="text" name="TrailerNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TrailerNo'])){ echo $_POST['TrailerNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>BOL Number<br><input type="text" name="BOLNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLNo'])){ echo $_POST['BOLNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>AX Purchase Order<br><input type="text" name="AxPurchaseOrder" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'])){ echo $_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                <td><a href="http://LaFargaWebSRV:8080/ScaleTimeDashboard.php" class="OrderButton">Dashboard</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

And then added the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ScaleWeight').change(UpdateInfo);
        $('#ScaleDiff').change(UpdateInfo);
    });

    function UpdateInfo() {
        var ScaleInWeight = $('#ScaleInWeight').val();
        var ScaleOutWeight = $('#ScaleOutWeight').val();
        var BOLWeight = $('#BOLWeight').val();

        var calScaleWeight = ScaleInWeight - ScaleOutWeight;
        var calScaleDiff = BOLWeight - calScaleWeight;

        $('#ScaleWeight').val(calScaleWeight);
        $('#ScaleDiff').val(calScaleDiff);
    }
</script>
```

When I test this out though nothing happens. What am I missing? Also, how would I make that so I get the absolute value so it is alway spositive?

Comment: use JavaScript and handle the "input" or perhaps "keyup" events of the textboxes, get the current values and then use those to calculate the other values, and then update the relevant part of the HTML with the new values. Did you do any research into this yet? There are plenty of examples of this kind of functionaliy online in tutorials, previous SO questions etc etc if you search.

Comment: googling [almost exactly the title of your question](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=update+text+box+in+HTML+when+another+textbox+is+filled+in&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=update+text+box+in+HTML+when+another+textbox+is+filled+in&aqs=chrome..69i57.6255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets quite a lot of useful results from this site and others

Comment: @ADyson I have done some research, but I don't use JavaScript hardly at all so that wasn't even on my radar. I will look into that search key.

Comment: well you _could_ do it using PHP but you'd have to keep posting back the whole page every time the user changed any of the fields. Slow and not very user-friendly. JS would be much easier. Have a read of some of those links, make an attempt and then post your stab at the JS code if you get stuck. It's not particularly tricky.

Comment: @ADyson will do, I've already gotten started. I will probably have questions though. Thanks for the starter!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Nothing happens because you don't have any elements whose id is "ScaleWeight" or "ScaleDiff"...so your change events are not attached to anything. Either add an "id" attribute to the relevant textboxes, or just a different selector to find each element. P.S. Since you're running the same event in either case, it might make sense to give them a single CSS class in common, so you only need to declare the "change" event once.

Comment: @ADyson like I said I don't use JavaScript hardly at all. Adding the `Id` did it. Now how do I make that an absolute value in the calculations?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=693yW93JDq7lkgXjl5_wAg&q=javascript+absolute+value&oq=javascript+absolute+value&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l10.4038.5552..5690...0.0..0.168.634.6j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i13j0i13i30j0i13i5i30j0i13i5i10i30.Omp7fIzQV7A

Comment: @ADyson The 2 calculated values. Right now I would get a negative value if when the `ScaleOutWeight` is larger than the `ScaleInWeight`. But I only want to have the absolute value. I tried adding `math.abs(calScaleWeight)`, but that did not work.

Comment: did not work means what? What error did you get? What value did calScaleWeight have at the time? First, try `Math.abs` instead of `math.abs` - JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: @ADyson Nothing happened, there was no error message. I figured it out though. Apperently JavaScript is case sensitive. I needed to use `Math.abs()` not `math.abs()`

Comment: "there was no error message"...i highly doubt it. you would have had an error message in your browser's console telling you it did not recognise the function

Comment: @ADyson That is probably true, but I don't have the console open at the moment so I did not capture it. Thanks for the help with this, if you want to post an answer based on your comments I'll select it, otherwise I'll post one tomorrow that shows what I did to get everything to work.

Comment: if you're working with JS you should _always_ have the console open. Then you'd have seen the problem immediately :-)

Comment: That's ok, you should post it - you wrote 90% of the JavaScript yourself, once you'd been pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @ADyson I will keep that in mind from now on. Looks like I'll have to learn more JavaScript. I'll post an answer then. Again Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @ADyson 's help, I was able to get this figured out. Here is what I did:

The form (yes this could be better with a css class instead of several change events declared, but I haven't done that yet):

```
    <form action="ScaleTimes.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ScaleTime">
        <table id="getApt" class="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton"  name="findApt" value="Find"></td>
                <td>Appointment Number<br><input type="text" name="AptNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptNo'])){ echo $_POST['AptNo'];} ?>" required autofocus="true"></td>
                <td>Appointment Date<br><input type="date" name="AptDate" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AptDate'])){ echo $_POST['AptDate'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Appointment Period<br>
                    <select name="AptPeriod">
                        <option value="">Select. . .</option>
                        <option value="3">6-8</option>
                        <option value="4">8-10</option>
                        <option value="5">10-12</option>
                        <option value="6">12-14</option>
                        <option value="7">14-16</option>
                        <option value="9">Open</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" id="ScaleInWeight" name="ScaleInWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale In Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleInDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleInDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleInDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Scale In Weight<br><input type="number" id="ScaleOutWeight" name="ScaleOutWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Out Date/Time<br><input type="datetime" name="ScaleOutDateTime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleOutDateTime'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer<br><input type="text" name="Customer" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Customer'])){ echo $_POST['Customer'];} ?>" autocomplete="on"></td>
                <td>Carrier<br><input type="text" name="Carrier" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Carrier'])){ echo $_POST['Carrier'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Driver<br><input type="text" name="Driver" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Driver'])){ echo $_POST['Driver'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Weighed By<br>
                    <select name="WeighedBy">
                        <option value="">Select Name...</option>
                        <option value="Tia Rian">Tia Rian</option>
                        <option value="Bruce Tippy">Bruce Tippy</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BOL Weight<br><input type="text" id="BOLWeight" name="BOLWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLWeight'])){ echo $_POST['BOLWeight'];} ?>" onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Weight<br><input type="text" id="ScaleWeight" name="ScaleWeight" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleWeight'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleWeight'];} ?>" disabled onchange="UpdateInfo()"></td>
                <td>Scale Difference<br><input type="text" id="ScaleDiff" name="ScaleDiff" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['ScaleDiff'])){ echo $_POST['ScaleDiff'];} ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Truck Number<br><input type="text" name="TruckNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TruckNo'])){ echo $_POST['TruckNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>Trailer Number<br><input type="text" name="TrailerNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TrailerNo'])){ echo $_POST['TrailerNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>BOL Number<br><input type="text" name="BOLNo" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['BOLNo'])){ echo $_POST['BOLNo'];} ?>"></td>
                <td>AX Purchase Order<br><input type="text" name="AxPurchaseOrder" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'])){ echo $_POST['AxPurchaseOrder'];} ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="OrderButton" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                <td><a href="http://LaFargaWebSRV:8080/ScaleTimeDashboard.php" class="OrderButton">Dashboard</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Then there is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ScaleWeight').change(UpdateInfo);
        $('#ScaleDiff').change(UpdateInfo);
    });

    function UpdateInfo() {
        var ScaleInWeight = $('#ScaleInWeight').val();
        var ScaleOutWeight = $('#ScaleOutWeight').val();
        var BOLWeight = $('#BOLWeight').val();

        var calScaleWeight = ScaleInWeight - ScaleOutWeight;
        var calScaleDiff = BOLWeight - Math.abs(calScaleWeight);

        $('#ScaleWeight').val(Math.abs(calScaleWeight));
        $('#ScaleDiff').val(Math.abs(calScaleDiff));
    }
</script>
```

Because I only need the differences and I don't care if they are negative I am using the absolute value in my calculations.